# Who is the receiver for a class method?

Tags: objective-c, runtime, class-method

If I define a class `Utils` like this:

```
@interface Utils: NSObject {

}

+ (NSInteger)getFreeSize;
```

who will get the message `getFreeSize` when I use it like this `[Utils getFreeSize];`?

Is any static instance created **under the hood** for `Util`'s representation at runtime? Who is the target for this message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class itself is the target, it's what you're calling the method on. There is an instance of the class object which exists, and then you can create instances of (instantiate) the class (there's a difference).

Comment: Hello Wain, thank you for your response! I think I found some info about this: http://www.sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2009/04/14/objc_explain_Classes_and_metaclasses.html.